# Testing ColdFusion 11 with ColdFusion 10 running

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

Has anybody using a Mac running Mavericks‎ tested ColdFusion 11 while running ColdFusion 10? Want to know how the 2 live together on the same machine.

I am using the default port for ColdFusion 10 (8500), therefore I would have to run ColdFusion 11 on another port.

Comment: What specific problem are you having/foreseeing with them running together?

Comment: Just asking before I try. I am not foreseeing any issue, I guess I should just go ahead and install and post any issues if I have them.

Comment: Yep, go ahead and try it. StackOverflow is for [solving problems](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - use a mailing list (e.g. [cf-talk](http://houseoffusion.com/cf-talk/)) or IRC ([##coldfusion on freenode](https://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=%23%23coldfusion)) or whatever when you want to ask something but don't yet have a specific issue.

Comment: sorry dude, didn't mean to upset you!

Comment: I'm not upset! :) Simply pointing out the Stack Overflow isn't always the right/best place for some questions.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, the ColdFusion installer is smart enough to detect the ports in use (8500 in your case) and will automatically show you the next available port no for ColdFusion 11 (when you chose the built-in server during insatll).

Else you can try the following:-

1. Open the cfroot\cfusion\runtime\conf\server.xml file.
2. Search for internal webserver start. Uncomment the following connector XML.

   `<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"port="8500" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8445"/>`
3. Change the port, save the file and then restart ColdFusion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Anit,thanks so very much for your comment, it was very helpful! As it turns out when you install ColdFusion builder(ThunderBeta) it automatically installs ColdFusion 11 for you(if you have that checked), and it installs it on port 8600. Not sure if the port is the new default port, or it was because it saw 8500 was in use. ColdFusion 11 rocks, I am having so much fun with it, thanks again!

Comment: Good to know that. We are glad to hear that ColdFusion 11 rocks. Cheers :)